# Ant design to display only allowed items when uploading entire folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, antd

I'm trying to upload a whole folder using the Dragger component from the ant design library, but I'm not sure how I can have only the allowed items to display as part of the final list that is shown to the user. As per the screenshot below it's possible to see that stats.js, my disallowed file, is displayed in red, indicating an error has happened, but it would be preferred that it's not there, so the user wouldn't have to delete it, but I haven't found a way to achieve this.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import {Upload, message} from 'antd';
import {InboxOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';

const {Dragger} = Upload;

function FileUpload(props) {

const allowedFiles = ["stats.json", "index.html"];

const config = {
    name: 'file',
    directory: true,
    onChange(info) {
        const {status} = info.file;
        if (status !== 'uploading') {
            console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
        }
        if (status === 'done') {
            props.onFileAdded(info.fileList)
        } else if (status === 'error') {
            message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
        }
    },
    beforeUpload: file => {
        if (allowedFiles.includes(file.name)) {
            return false;
        }
    },

};

return (
    <div>
        <Dragger {...config}>
            <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
                <InboxOutlined/>
            </p>
            <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
            <p className="ant-upload-hint">
                Support for a single or bulk upload.
            </p>
        </Dragger>
    </div>
);

}

export default FileUpload;
```

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Desmond's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64762786/6654475), using a list managed through states worked for me.

```
const allowedFiles = ["stats.json", "index.html"];
const [list, setList] = useState([])

const config = {
    name: 'file',
    directory: true,
    fileList: list,
    onChange(info) {
        const {status} = info.file;
        if (status !== 'uploading') {
            console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
        }
        if (status === 'done') {
            props.onFileAdded(info.fileList)
        } else if (status === 'error') {
            message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
        }
    },
    beforeUpload: file => {
        if (allowedFiles.includes(file.name)) {
            setList(prev => [...prev, file])
            return false;
        }
    },

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `accept` props to `Dragger` component.

Exp: If only allow image files

```
accept: 'images/*'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I had tried that before, with `accept: allowedFiles`, but it wouldn't work. I've updated the question with this piece.

Comment: Or you can control the files by state. Use the `fileList` property in Dragger component. Add a filter function inside the `beforeUpdate` function, and set the filtered files to the state and pass to `fileList`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that worked. I'll paste my code here for reference.